# How to render inside a modal inside a nav-tabs?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig

I'm trying to render a form with a modal, that is setted as active by a link in my nav-tabs. But when I put this line into the modal :

```
{{ render(controller('AcmeBundle:Acme:new')) }}
```

I cant open my nav-tab anymore. The modal is working into the nav-tabs, and the render is working in the modal without the nav-tabs.

Here is the code :

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toogle">a
                <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="{{path('index')}}">aaaa</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myActivityModal">aa</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li></ul>
     <div class="modal fade" id="myActivityModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myActivityModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myActivityModalLabel">aa</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    {{ render(controller('AcmeBundle:Acme:new')) }}
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks for your help, and sorry if it was obvious :/

Edit:

```
newAction :
/**
 * Displays a form to create a new Acme entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="new")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function newAction()
{
    $entity = new Acme();
    $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

The nav is rendered but I cant open any of the tabs in him. When I comment my render, everything is working fine.

Comment: Can we see the newAction please ?
And nothing is display in your browser console ?

Comment: The newAction is the default one (generated with the crud command), and is correctly rendered in the modal, when I dont put the modal in a nav-tabs. I edited my post with the new action

Comment: You have syntax error in twig. There are no closing <li/> and <ul/> tags after modal div.

Comment: They are, just didnt copied it, the code take 200 lines, with other tab in my nav bar, the modal is outside of the navbar (and it doesnt change anything to put it in)
edit: I tried to put the modal out of the navbar, hes working and rendering correctly, but I still cant open any tabs of the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

You do a render of a controllerwhich return only an array of values. You have to return a twig view to fill this modal.

```
return $this->render('AcmeBundle:Acme:form.html.twig', array(
    'entity' => $entity,
    'form'   => $form->createView(),
);
```

Comment: Was using annotation to render the twig view, thats not the point. My render is working, my modal is working, both are already working together.
My navbar is working too, with my modal. But when I try to render my view in the modal that is in the navbar, it doesnt work anymore.